# Does every matrix that is onto (one-to-one) have a right inverse (left inverse)?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix that is onto (one-to-one), how can I prove (or disprove) that there exists an $n\times m$ matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$ ($BA=I)$?

I feel like I am running into the same problem for both proofs. For onto:

Assume $A$ is onto. Then for an arbitrary $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, there exists a $\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\vec{y}=\vec{x}$. I think I need to find a way to define $B$ as mapping each $\vec{y}$ to $\vec{x}$, but I am not sure how to show that such a $B$ would be a linear transformation / matrix.

For one-to-one:

Assume $A$ is one-to-one. Let $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary. Then let $A\vec{x}=\vec{y}$. Define a function $B$ that maps from $\vec{y}$ to $\vec{x}$. Since $A$ is one-to-one, we know that such a function $B$ is well-defined. However, once again I am not sure if $B$ is a matrix or not.

Comment: Don’t define $B$ on **every** vector: define it the standard basis and then verify it work on every vector. Same for the second part: start with a basis for the image, then extend it to a basis, then use a change-of-basis matrix to get $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is onto, then $m \leq n$ and it is possible to perform row operations so that the $m$ rows and first $m$ columns are in row-echelon form.  The product of all of these operations (written as matrices) is the right inverse for $A$.